# Makes an blank 3s image section in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, editing, code

I have a video. And I want to make the image blank (black screen) 3s every 1 minute, sounds like the original video as I described in the following image. So please help me code ffmpeg.
I use Google translate. sorry if you do not understand

Image:

[image]

Comment: Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPb2h.png

Comment: @Nakini: Please don’t download and re-upload an image just to embed it in a post. All you have to do is edit the ‘‘markdown’’.

Comment: @Scott, my sincere apologies. I didn't think about the editing markdown option. I will keep that in find in future.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video -vf drawbox=t=fill:enable='gt(mod(t,60),57)' -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The `drawbox` filter defaults to black color and a 3-pixel hollow box surrounding the whole frame. I've set the thickness parameter to `fill` so that a solid box is drawn. The `enable` option activates the filter only for times which are 3 seconds less than a multiple of 60 i.e. 57-60, 117-120, 177-180...

Comment: Now I want to convert the 3s blank into a sketch video filter effect. thank you
See image below

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFBr.jpg

Comment: Make that a new question.

Comment: New question posted [here](https://superuser.com/q/1328534/302907).