# Make 3s sketch filter effect every minute in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video. And I want to make the image with 3s sketch filter effect every 1 minute, sounds like the original video as I described in the following image. So please help me code ffmpeg. I use Google translate. Sorry if you do not understand.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to run an [edge detector](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#edgedetect).

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "edgedetect=enable='gt(mod(t,60),57)',negate" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The negate filter is added since the output of edgedetect is white edges on black canvas,

If the edgedetect options don't provide fine enough tweaking, run a [convolution](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#convolution) filter beforehand.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "convolution=0 -1 0 -1 5 -1 0 -1 0:0 -1 0 -1 5 -1 0 -1 0:0 -1 0 -1 5 -1 0 -1 0:0 -1 0 -1 5 -1 0 -1 0:enable='gt(mod(t,60),57)',edgedetect=enable='gt(mod(t,60),57)',negate" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: I do not know how to run edge detector like that? Can you guide me?
I just run the ffmpeg command as you share it and it outputs the image like this. It is not the original image of the video.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh5bR.png